# Allure report build step in the Teamcity returns "Cannot copy history file" error

Tags: allure

Allure report is added as a build step in the Teamcity.

Althoug the build step is passed successfully and report is generated, I get the following error in the build log:

Step 2/2: Allure Report (Allure Report)
.......

Cannot copy history file. Reason: C:\BuildAgent\work\5cb9fadc413325b7\project\allure-results\history\categories-trend.json
[21:55:58]
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\BuildAgent\work\5cb9fadc413325b7\project\allure-results\history\categories-trend.json
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:81)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:3016)
    at io.qameta.allure.teamcity.AllureBuildServiceAdapter.copyHistoryToResultsPath(AllureBuildServiceAdapter.java:168).....

From the error message I understand that mentioned file can't be copied as it already exists. But I don't have any idea how to fix it.

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this issue? Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I could not understand for long time why is it?

**What's the reason?**

There are an ***allure-results*** folder(folder with current allure data) and an ***allure-report*** folder(with currently generated report).We are running test again....

The allure plugin after how tests finished does

1)  Copies a ***history*** folder from previous generated ***allure-report*** folder to the current ***allure-results*** folder

2) Generates new report from ***allure-results*** folder using exist copied the ***history*** folder. The ***history*** folder is needed to the new report will be generate with history. trend([Allure reports to see historic trends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376630/allure-reports-to-see-historic-trends))

And my problem was a build agent has not access to copied ***history*** folder.
So I had to manual changed the right for ***allure-report*** folder. Then the build agent began to have a corresponding right to ***history*** folder(which was copied) and the error is disappeared

Comment: How did you exactly change the rights?